# Setting property value from another properties

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have a custom control (disabled edit) where I want to show current logged in `Domain\User`.

I set property like this:

```
<Property Id="PROP_DOMAINUSER" Value="[%USERDOMAIN]\[LogonUser]"></Property>
```

But what I see in edit box is exact text - `[%USERDOMAIN]\[LogonUser]` and not actual domain and user.

How do I initialize property value from another property then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create a type 51 custom action to set the property, this can be achieved using the [SetProperty](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_setproperty.htm) element.  Remember to schedule this before your custom control gets displayed.

```
<SetProperty Id="INSTALL_USERNAME" Value="[%USERDOMAIN]\[%USERNAME]" />
```

You should then use the property `[INSTALL_USERNAME]` in your control.

**Edit:**

To schedule the custom action use the Before or After attribute, if you are unsure where to schedule it use a tool like orca to see what order things are happening in, here's an example of the custom action running after After="InstallInitialize"

```
<SetProperty Id="INSTALL_USERNAME" Value="[%USERDOMAIN]\[%USERNAME]" After="InstallInitialize" />
```

Comment: How can I schedule it? I see the Before or After attribute must be used but no matter what standard action I use, it remains empty... Can you please refer me to the information? I rather that to be initialized as setup begins. thanks