# Wix Toolset - Compound properties within one property

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

Using Wix, I am publishing a warning dialog box if the OS of the local machine matches one of several valid operating systems. I can perform this check by putting, for example, `VersionNT = 601` in the conditional part of the publish tag.

Because I need to check for multiple operating systems and types (server, domain controller, etc.) I'd like to store some of these conditions in properties and use those custom properties in multiple publish conditions.

Something like:

```
<Property Id="WinServer08R2" Value="VersionNT = 601 AND MsiNTProductType = 3" />
```

Then use this property somewhat like this:

```
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="WarningDlg">
    WinServer08R2 AND Not Installed
</Publish>
...
```

Neither this method nor slight variations on it have worked for me thus far. Has anyone else tried this and gotten it to work? One might suggest that I simply use parentheses and make it work, but this is a simplified example and the conditions would quickly get out of hand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting property value from another properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135160/setting-property-value-from-another-properties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Property/@Value` (and the inner text for that matter) aren't a condition, they're the actual value of the property. So what you have right now, is a property named `WinServer08R2` with the literal value of `VersionNT = 601 AND MsiNTProductType = 3`. So `WinServer08R2` always evaluates to true, because it has a value.

You should be able to verify this by opening the resulting MSI with Orca and looking at the `Property` table.

What you want is to set your property based on a condition.

```
<SetProperty Id="WinServer08R2" Value="1">
    VersionNT = 601 AND MsiNTProductType = 3
</SetProperty>
```

Then you'd just have to test the property using `WinServer08R2 = 1` or `WinServer08R2`.

Don't forget to sequence the custom action using the `Before`, `After` or `Sequence` attributes.